# Unable to Connect to FMS

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-media-server, netconnection

Why cant i connect? When i run the application i receive NetConnection.failed in the output. Can you please take a carefull look at my code. I believe my string url is correct. I am unsure is my FMS is down or if theres a code error.

Thank You

```
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.media.Microphone;
import fl.controls.Button;

var nc:NetConnection;
var ns:NetStream;
var cam:Camera;
var microphone:Microphone;
var vid:Video;
var connectButton:Button;

//Connecting to Flash Media Server
nc = new NetConnection();

nc.connect("rtmfp:/fms/streamExample");

nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);

function netHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    switch (event.info.code)
    {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
        {
            connectButton.label = "Disconnect";
            connectButton.enabled = true;
            sendButton.enabled = true;
            onConnect();
            break;
        }

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Closed":
        {
            connectButton.label = "Connect";
            connectButton.enabled = true;
            sendButton.enabled = false;
            nc.close();
            break;
        }

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
        {
            trace("Sorry your connection failed");
            break;
        }

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected":
        {
            trace("Oops the connection has been rejected");
            break;
        }
    }
}
ns = new NetStream(nc);

ns.publish("live", "viewing");

ns.attachCamera();


//Setting the video
var vid:Video = new Video();
vid.height = cam.height;
vid.width = cam.width;
vid.x = 10;
vid.y = 10;
addChild(vid);

cam = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(400, 300, 20);
cam.setQuality(0, 85);
cam.setKeyFrameInterval(18);
vid.attachCamera();
addChild(cam);

//Setting the audio
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
microphone.framesPerPacket = 1;
microphone.setSilenceLevel(0, 200);
microphone.gain = 50;
NetStream.attachAudio(microphone);
```

Comment: `"rtmfp:/fms/streamExample"` is not a valid connection string.  Should look like this:   `"rtmfp://server.com/applicationName"`    There are a lot of nuances with rtmfp,  try getting your application working with rtmp (note the missing 'f') first.

Comment: Also, as an aside, you'll want your net connection listeners added before you call `connect` as a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Flash Media Server is on the same machine than the one your testing your application from, you should change the URL of server with `rtmfp://localhost/streamExample`
If your server is on another machine, then you just have to replace `localhost` with the IP address of the machine running the server.

You should also add the event listener on your `NetConnection` before you perform the `connect()` call.

To help you known the reason of the failure, you might want to trace the description of your event as well.

Here is a sample with all these indications:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);
nc.connect("rtmfp:/localhost/streamExample");

function netHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    switch (event.info.code)
    {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
        {
            connectButton.label = "Disconnect";
            connectButton.enabled = true;
            sendButton.enabled = true;
            onConnect();
            break;
        }
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Closed":
        {
            connectButton.label = "Connect";
            connectButton.enabled = true;
            sendButton.enabled = false;
            nc.close();
            break;
        }
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
        {
            trace("Sorry your connection failed");
            trace("Reason is: " + event.info.description);
            break;
        }
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected":
        {
            trace("Oops the connection has been rejected");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys! And, im really sorry for my late belated reply. Problem was with the string address it was incorrect. For some reason I thought you put the the event listener after the nc.connect but thanks for the tip anyway it worked!

Comment: @user2160610 Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you as it could help someone else